# Font specifying location of job offer is badly readable due to bad kerning

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, stack-overflow-jobs

The font and style that is used to display the location of a job offer is badly readable. It is very difficult to tell apart an `rn` from a `m`. In the specific case shown below both readings lead to sensible German word.

[image: image showing that discerning rn and m is difficult]

Comment: Related: http://www.frederiksamuel.com/blog/images/keming.jpg

Comment: We currently don't have plans to update this. This is the default type and kerning we use sitewide.

Comment: Sitewide? Sry, but now I need to test *kerning* on *cornrnents*.

Comment: Related: *pom.xml* makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: @Donna That seems like an incredibly reactive position to start from. No "Is it a problem, how widespread is it, is it confusing users, etc", just straight to "Well that's the way we do things here".