# When someone's creating multiple accounts just to post time-wasting questions, is flagging useful?

Tags: discussion, flags

There's a user posting fake questions on SO right now from a variety of accounts. Some are fairly obvious, others are carefully-crafted to waste people's time (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185105/assemblyerror-cannot-recursively-extend-an-exotic-object-in-chrome-not-in-mo) [10k+ only, it's deleted now], which lasted for two weeks). His posts are like pr0n: Once you've seen one, you mostly know them when you see them. The latest I've run across is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430602/javascript-jquery-is-not-a-function-how) [also now deleted], for which the account has not yet been destroyed.

Naturally, eventually the questions are closed and deleted, and eventually the accounts are destroyed.

When we see one of these, in addition to close-voting and delete-voting when possible, is flagging them useful in terms of accelerating a user-ban or even IP ban? Or do questions downvoted into oblivion, closed, and deleted automatically trigger some follow-up?

I want to interrupt and where possible prevent this behavior, but I don't want to waste mods' time.

Comment: It took me a moment to understand what you mean by _pron_. Maybe I would have been faster if you had written _pom_...

Comment: I flagged this one as "User states they're here to post a 'joke' question daily." and it appears to have done the trick. Imagine it accrued a few similar ones. :-)

Comment: The first question doesn't seem specially bad. It's just not reproducible, just like gazillions of other questions. I would have flagged the second one as offensive because is says rape is a huge fun.

Comment: @honk _pr0n_ is the standard way of avoiding censors that block "porn", he probably figured most people that have been online long enough have seen it.

Comment: What I want to know is who upvotes these questions.

Comment: @JustinTime: I cannot say that I avoid that topic, but that was new to me. So, thanks for your explanation ;) BTW: T.J. changed the text from _pron_ to _pr0n_ shortly after I commented. The latter one is more obvious to me...

Comment: After fake news with fabricated evidence we now have fake questions with fabricated errors. 2017 will be just as brilliant as 2016 :-(

Comment: @honk You're welcome.  It mainly seems to appear in MMO gaming communities, but it's well enough known that at least a few of them have started censoring it, too.

Comment: @Oriol: "The first question doesn't seem specially bad. It's just not reproducible, just like gazillions of other questions." And yet look at all the people who were baited into trying to diagnose the ultimately made-up "problem". We already have enough of a problem with the gazillions of other questions by legitimately clueless or uncooperative users - we don't need *more* of them from trolls.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, I didn't mean the question is OK. But I don't think that being asked by a troll makes it worse than other non-reproducible questions. What we need to fix is the amount of these questions. Some kind of mjölnir for off-topic.

Comment: @Oriol: For users who are savvy enough to disengage when appropriate, it's not a problem. But as with any other disruptive user, trolls need to be identified and removed ASAP, because the "better" (read: more convincing) questions they ask the better a position they are in to cause needless trouble for everyone involved.

Comment: @honk That just makes me think of Pom Bears

Comment: @SGR: Tasty! ;) But there was a discussion on kerning recently and I remembered [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339606/font-specifying-location-of-job-offer-is-badly-readable-due-to-bad-kerning#comment422269_339606)...

Comment: @honk: LOL!! ...

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to refer to another user--even a demonstratively problematic one--in a pejorative term like "twit."  Not because it necessarily inaccurate in this or any other case, but because of the tone it sets.

Comment: @WayneConrad: To my mind, "twit" (rather than the variant with an "a") is the perfect term for someone actively seeking to waste the time of people trying to be helpful. It's pejorative, and rightly so, but not obscene or defamatory. But I take your point and have edited accordingly. And moreover, I usually prefer to focus on behavior (failed to in this case), and the terms I used originally (twit, jerk) can't be applied (elegantly) to behavior. :-)

Comment: @JustinTime references to pr0n always remind me of [not pr0n](http://notpron.org/notpron/notpron.htm) don't ask why.

Comment: @honk "pr0n" reads as a word to me without difficulty... it did, however, take a second for me to figure out why it appeared you were asking him to write "pom" instead. What did a brand of pomegranite juice have to do with anything?!

Comment: Dudes a loser nuff said...

Comment: @Lankymart: Damn. Now I wasted 2 hours in order to reach level 8...

Comment: On the last line of the 2nd deleted question you linked to: "*P.S. Another IP address... :P*"... I'm guessing we haven't seen the last of this person...

Comment: @DavidMakogon: Oh, almost certainly not. Eventually they'll get tired of the game and stop doing it. Until then, we just need to keep taking appropriate action on their posts.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yes, do flag problematic users. Make sure you highlight the user being the primary problem, not just the questions they post. Eventually all of the mods, as well as the community managers, will catch wind of who this clown is and we'll figure out exactly how to deal with them.

More likely than not, you won't be the only user flagging their posts for moderator attention. That's fine; the more users flagging (correctly) the better.

Comment: Just curious, how do you generally deal with them? What is the severest action possible?

Comment: @DarkKnight hanging (although I've heard that fire squads have also been used in the past).

Comment: @DarkKnight Your account is banned for [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/329261)

Comment: @SGR and you lose a randomly chosen hat

Comment: good thing he has several :/

Comment: @SGR : lol..Preview of your message in notification area gave me a mini heart attack. I thought this message was from administrator. :)

Answer (score -3):

Maybe there should be a `mark this question as a deliberate attempt to cheat the reputation system (cloning)` flag

-- or better yet..

only let users upvote stuff so many times without first making useful comments that are upvoted by  users with at least XXXXX reputation (like 5 up votes from reputable users  = 2 upvotes from the person who is upvoted).

This would at least force abnormal behavior by the offenders trying to cheat and gain more reputation by using multiple accounts, which could potentially be traced by looking for users who are doing lots and lots of upvoting on users previously  flagged as `trying to cheat the reputation system`

I'm sure theres an answer to this problem hidden somehow in a system like this one...

Comment: That's an awfully specific flag. We already have _"requires moderator intervention"_. There's already a small rep requirement to be able to upvote.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know. Was just kind of thinking of solutions to the problem in the question -- having a unique flag for tracking  multiple-account offenders would provide a unique way to automaticallynarrow down which users are behind such actions, giving the moderators a streamlined way to track down the bogus accounts and delete their questions